# Where is the file directory of Sales Order Grid?

Tags: magento2

I want to know which class is responsible for setting order grid.

I want to know the file location of Grid.php or other files structure where _prepareColumns and _prepareColection method located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry Dear you won't find this methods or `grid.php` for this

`Magento2` uses UI component for loading grid

file responsible for loading grid is

`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

Comment: let me check please

Comment: Dear Murtuza. I just want to change Grand Total Colum value. i make muti-vendor site.
I already filter order grid. every admin can see those order in which admin product is exist.
Now Grand Total is shown total of all items. I want to change Grand total value according to total of own product.
kindly guid me little bit how can change Grand Total Colum value.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @HaFizUmer, if this is your requirement then I suggest you to create completely your own grid

Comment: in `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/di.xml` this line `<item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>` pass the collection